# Pixel Art icons

Tags: icons

I'm working on my web project and am looking for the way 
all the big ones like twitter, facebook, etc. created their icon set.

Did you ever take a look at their sprite?
https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yI/x/4jB4tvIAAbU.png

How do they draw those tiny icons?
Is that technique called pixel art? And where can I hire someone to draw some for me?

I'm sorry if this is not the place to ask, had no idea where to post this.

Comment: http://icon.designcrowd.com/bids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create pixel art using a variety of programs, including Adobe Photoshop, Fireworks, etc, but there are also freeware and inexpensive offerings too.

Check out this one: http://code.google.com/p/grafx2/

If you are not familiar with graphic design, you can hire someone using a freelance service, such as Freelancer.com, Odesk.com, or a variety of others. Just Google it.

Yes, it is called pixel art, and it uses a limited palette of colors (usually 8 or 16 bit) -- where each pixel is represented by one 8-bit byte (maximum colors: 256). As opposed to modern graphics which use a technique of anti-aliasing which blurs the edge to create the illusion of a smooth edge.